# What directory is the default bash directory

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, ps1

I am using the bash console for Ubuntu and my console location is

```
user@MyServer:~$
```

If `user@MyServer:/$` is the root directory, what is `user@MyServer:~$` ?

Comment: In Linux `~` is Your HOME directory

Comment: You may issue `pwd` to determine your home directory. By default, it should be `/home/{username}/`

Comment: `echo $PS1` would tell you what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~` represents your home directory. If you are logged in as root, this will typically be `/root` if you are logged in with another user (say with username `user`) this will typically be `/home/user`. The best way to know for certain though is either run `echo ~` which will print where `~` points to, or you can run the `pwd` command while in `~` which will show your present working directory - this command is generally useful to know when navigating.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in other replies, it's your home directory, which is shortened to `~`.

You can find out what directory you're in using the `pwd` command. eg:

```
[atticus:pgl]:~ $ pwd
/home/pgl
```

Answer (score 1):

“user@MyServer:~$”  is the command prompt. You can echo $PS1 to see the setting of your environment.

Answer (score 0):

Its your home directory you can go to your home directory by `cd ~`

Comment: is this the same as user@MyServer:/home$

Comment: @Andrew If your home directory is /home ,then yes. But probably the home directory for user@MyServer is /home/user

Comment: no you can see it by executing pwd command, user@MyServer:~$ is your   /home/user directory

Comment: `cd` is a shell builtin which does `cd $HOME` if no arguments get passed. So no point to do `cd ~`, just `cd`

Answer (score 0):

Not always, you can list all users' home directory by:

```
cut -d : -f1,6 /etc/passwd
```

so you will get different paths, some under /export/home/USERNAME, some under /home/USERNAME, some has no home directory. For root account, normal / is its home directly.